# Scroll button jQuery for scroll up and scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my site i am having a list of items where i am using scroll bar to scroll the items.[image]

Now i want to replace that bar with two buttons which working for scroll up and scroll down which can auto hide if there is not any item is available to display.
[image]

If is there any plugins are available please do let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scrollTop()` can help you here. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Example:

```js
$('.scroll-up-button').on('click', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); // current page position
    $(window).scrollTop(y - 150); // scroll up 150px
});


$('.scroll-down-button').on('click', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); // current page position
    $(window).scrollTop(y + 150); // scroll down 150px
});
```

Obviously this is not a complete solution, but could help you get started in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/rr625z6c/#&togetherjs=kNGOccBELi)

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Scroll To Top</a>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollToTop{
    width:100px; 
    height:130px;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background: whiteSmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:fixed;
    top:75px;
    right:40px;
    display:none;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: This is not the functionality requested in the question.  This will only create a scroll up button which will scroll to the top of the page.  @Akash was asking for two buttons that could scroll up and down the page in increments, see my answer.

Comment: @winseybash Akash asked for auto hide feature there

Comment: He asked for auto hide if no items are available to display on the page, not if the page is scrolled to the top.  Seeing as we have not been provided with any code it can be quite hard to implement this blind.

Comment: have u checked fiddle provided. It has the body section as well with dummy data :)

Comment: @vispan i was looking for something where i can add two buttons to scroll which i can autohide if no items are left to show.