# Scroll Up/Down want to slide in parts not in once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a slider on my web page for that i used jQuery Function

to scroll down

```
jQuery("#downClick").click(function() {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(document).height() }, "slow");
        });
```

to scroll up

```
jQuery("#upClick").click(function(){ //Click event to scroll to top ==>> Slider 
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```

My page is having too much data to display, so when a person clicks on this buttons either he navigates to bottom or top in once.

Does anybody can suggest me how can i change to something like if i want to scroll up it will scroll up with multiple steps not in once.

Comment: Why is there a `return false;`? It may causes the issue.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "scroll up with multiple steps not in once"? Do you want it to scroll up, stop, scroll up, stop, etc until you reach the top? Or just scroll part of the way up the page?

Comment: @NickG Yeah, my requirement is like this: scroll up, stop, scroll up, stop, etc until I reach to the top?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#upClick').on('click', function() {
var scrollIndex = $(window).scrollTop(); // current page position
$(window).scrollTop(y - 150); // scroll up 150px
}
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717478/scroll-button-jquery-for-scroll-up-and-scroll-down)!